# Execute callback when jest mock function was called

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have this test:

```
describe("onAfterSwipe", () => {
  it("Should call a handler after swiping", async () => {
    const onAfterSwipe = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Swipeable onAfterSwipe={onAfterSwipe}>Hello</Swipeable>
    );

    swipe(wrapper, 500);

    await wait(600);

    expect(onAfterSwipe).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

I'm waiting for 600ms to check if the function was called (onAfterSwipe is called after an animation end), i would like to do something like:

```
describe("onAfterSwipe", () => {
  it("Should call a handler after swiping", (done) => {
    const onAfterSwipe = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Swipeable onAfterSwipe={onAfterSwipe}>Hello</Swipeable>
    );

    swipe(wrapper, 500);

    onAfterSwipe.called((args) => {
      expect(onAfterSwipe).toHaveBeenCalledWith("right");
      done();
    })
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with **jest**, but from the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestfnimplementation) I assume you can do this:

```
const onAfterSwipe = jest.fn(args => {
   // expect args to be "right"
   done();
});
```